# How can show alert message in node.js

Tags: node.js, alert

what should i do ?? I work on node.js . I can not use alert("sometext");

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("project");

  dbo.collection("Register").findOne({Email:  req.body.email} , function(err, result) {
  if (result.Password == req.body.psw) {
      console.log("Correct go next page");
    }
    else{
      window.alert("sometext");
    });
    db.close();
  });
});
```

output = ReferenceError: window is not defined

Comment: There is no window with node.  It runs on the server.

Comment: How can i print Alert message sir.

Comment: Can you tell why you need : window.alert("sometext")? 
And are you are writing an API using MongoDB with Nodejs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NodeJS runs on the console of the given operating system, that said, window.alert is actually a browser API command, you cannot use it, as alternatives, you can:

1. Use console.log that will output information on the STDOUT(Aka the standard output, aka will just print on the console).
2. Use console.error, that will do exactly the same as above, but will pipe the content to STDERR, that can be usefull for logging or process output identification purposes.
3. Wrap your Node application on a container like [Electron](https://electronjs.org/), that, to be honest, is overkill.
4. And finally, calling the **native dialog API** from your OS:

To call a native dialog, you need acess to the OS native libraries, you can do that using the [Node FFI module](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi/wiki/Node-FFI-Tutorial) that allows you to bind those libraries.
Or, for the sake of simplicity, just use one of existing implementations of that function, like: [node-native-dialog](https://github.com/s-h-a-d-o-w/node-native-dialog#readme), [mitsobox](https://github.com/jimfilippou/mitsobox) or [dialog](https://github.com/tomas/dialog).

> Disclaimer: I did not develop or can attest the quality of those
>   modules, use at your own risk, if native dialogs are really required
>   to your development, implement your own binding of the OS libraries.

Comment: This could be useful: https://github.com/bat-tomr/dialog-node

Comment: to clarify, Electron is recommended here because it helps interface between Node and OS?

Comment: @shea This is not a recommendation but rather a list of possible options. Yes, Electron is on this list because it allows calling native dialogs(file picker, alerts, etc) easily. This answer was written 5 years ago, I highly recommend searching for other modern options :)

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you know, which OS you are running on, the most reliable way would be to use it's native shell (so far, most NPM packages I tried did not work out of the box). For windows Powershell, it can look like this:

```
const { spawnSync } = require('child_process');

const messag = "Hello world";

spawnSync("powershell.exe", [`
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework;
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('${messag}');
`]);
```

You can also show prompts, like yes / not, etc. See more info [here](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2016/06/09/display-gui-message-boxes-in-powershell.aspx)

**Update** [dialog package](https://github.com/tomas/dialog) seems to work out of the box, though does not look to have as much options as what is available with PowerShell.

Comment: This gives me:

`Unable to find type [System.Windows.MessageBox].
At line:1 char:79
+ ... tationCore,PresentationFramework; [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show(' ...
+                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Windows.MessageBox:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound`

Comment: @ClausConrad any chance you are on Linux or using PowershellCore?

Comment: I tried with PowerShell Core 7.2.5 and Windows PowerShell 5.1 and got the same error message in both.

Comment: @ClausConrad im guessing the problem lies with Powershell on that specific machine lacking something necessary, maybe DLLs for presentation framework? Can run that code in PS directly and check? Alternatively, can you use the approach of running a process from Node just to show a message, but try using some other shell / process?

Comment: That was already running directly in PS. Just tried on another machine (also running Windows 11, could that be the problem?) and got the same error. I've found another approach, no issue, just curious why this did not work.

Answer (score 4):

Install cross-platform, isomorphic alert, for Node and browser (previously alert-node)
`npm i alert -g`

Use this lib:

```js
var alert = require('alert');
alert('Hello');
```

Comment: Just in case someone comes across this, that package is deprecated in favor of `node-notifier`, which is much better than I had time to build in `alert`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find where it is documented but I have been using `global.alert()` in my `react-native` code for debugging purposes. The app is being controlled by `Appium` so I can't use `console.log`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a title and message body to the message box too.

```js
const { spawnSync } = require('child_process');

const title = "My Title";
const message = "Hello, world!";

spawnSync("powershell.exe", ["-Command", `Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework; [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('${message.replace(/'/g, "''")}', '${title.replace(/'/g, "''")}', 0);`]);
```

The `0` at the end of the `[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show()` method call specifies that the message box should have an OK button.